# error en Magento 2 (Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page)

Tags: php, magento, magento2, marketplace

I have been trying to make a small store in magento, but an error has occurred when I do different actions within the page when you browse in the store, this error occurs when I want to create a new user or when I want to create a user or when I want add a product to the cart.

I already changed the max_input_vars value of my php.ini file and I see that in most cases it works but in mine it doesn't.

It may be that I do not have a well done configuration because I just installed magento and I am testing with the products that I just registered, but if this is the case, you cannot find a way to correct it.

Comment: Please produce minimum usable code for us to try and see where the issue is. Where is the issue being shown? Can you show that code?